# Trouble accessing 'CaptureController' in Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, webapi

I'm currently working on an Angular project and encountering an issue with `CaptureController`. I'm trying to instantiate it using `let controller = new CaptureController()`, but I'm getting an error saying `Cannot find name 'CaptureController'`.

I'm working on a project in which user is giving a test and I'm taking screenshot using get Display Media in which user selects the either browser, window or entire screen but I want to restrict user from selecting browser or window I want to share only entire screen.

**Expecting:** this `CaptureController` helps to stop user to go on the shared tab or window.

**Issue:** Not able to use it properly in angular getting error in implementing and the error is `Cannot find name 'CaptureController'`

Comment: Should that be `new CaptureController()` without the space?

Comment: Yes, it is new CaptureController()

Comment: Where does `CaptureController` come from?  It's not something built into web browsers, so it must come from your Angular project somewhere.  It's hard to figure out why you are having this problem since you haven't shown any code at all.  My guess is that you have not imported the file that contains this class into whatever you are working with.

Comment: check [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CaptureController#browser_compatibility)

Comment: CaptureController comes from getDisplayMedia function of javascript that I'm using to capture screenshot of the shared screen and I have found out the solution. So, thanks for your participation.